# How to fix textDirection for numeric TextView Android?

Tags: android, textview

I have a text view which need to display a numeric code eg: `1234`.

This works fine when the language is any left to right language like English. But when I switch to a right to left language like arabic the text field starts displaying `4321`. The way to fix this is by `textDirection='ltr (or locale)'`, but this also changes the text view gravity to the other direction.

Is there an elegant way to change the `textDirection` but not effect the gravity of the text field ? Or do I have to do a code check and flip gravity also or reverse the text if its numeric.

Please suggest the right way to fix this.

Comment: just set gravity on your TextView . for example `android:gravity="right"`. This will pin the text to the right side of the view

Comment: But then, it will fail for `ltr` language

Comment: Ok, maybe you have to declare `layout-ldrtl` resource directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `TextView` with `textDirection='ltr'` and `layout_width='wrap_content'` inside of `LinearLayout` with `layout_width='match_parent'` with `gravity='start'` or maybe `gravity='end'`.
This make your Textview stay correct because of fixed direction while gravity will change by phone system language.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured the right way to solve this, I used the `BidiFormatter` to encode my text before putting it into the UI:

`BidiFormatter.getInstance().bidi.unicodeWrap("1234")`

Thanks for the help !